# How to change permalink of default post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the permalink of default post to `\blog\post-name` but at the same time I don't want to change permalink of other custom post types.

Comment: you can change permalink on per-post basis

Comment: can you tell me plz @entre

Comment: @Mudassarali What did you tried to do it programatically

Comment: i tried to change permalink of post whose post type is "post"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permalink structure of "posts" in Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks.

Permalink structure of eventual Custom Post Types doesn't change beacuse is set for every custom post type, via plugin or script (for your information, it happens with the `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'your-cpt-permalink-slug')` instruction).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom post type . Dont forget to change text-domain 'booksinfo'

Add this code to functions.php

```
function blog_post_type() {
// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => esc_html__( 'Blogs', 'booksinfo' ),
        'singular_name'       => esc_html__( 'Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'menu_name'           => esc_html__( 'Blogs', 'booksinfo' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => esc_html__( 'Parent Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'all_items'           => esc_html__( 'All Blogs', 'booksinfo' ),
        'view_item'           => esc_html__( 'View Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'add_new_item'        => esc_html__( 'Add new Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'add_new'             => esc_html__( 'Add New', 'booksinfo' ),
        'edit_item'           => esc_html__( 'Edit Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'update_item'         => esc_html__( 'Update Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'search_items'        => esc_html__( 'Search Blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'not_found'           => esc_html__( 'Not Found', 'booksinfo' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => esc_html__( 'Not found in Trash', 'booksinfo' ),
    );
     
// Set other options for Custom Post Type
     
    $args = array(
        'label'               => esc_html__( 'blog', 'booksinfo' ),
        'description'         => esc_html__( 'blogs news', 'booksinfo' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-star-empty',
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag','category'),

);
     
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'blog', $args );
 
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_post_type', 0 );
```